# failed binder transaction on emulator 2.2 but not on 4.1

Tags: android, android-widget, imageview

I am setting an imageview to an image from the sd card. This runs smoothly on the android emulator 4.1, however on the emulator with android version 2.2 it returns a failed binder transaction. I find this very odd and can not figure out what the problem could be. The image image is set the following way:

```
               try{
                    String pathName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Drop Insight/" + c.getString(iID) + ".png";
                    File path = new File(pathName);
                    if(path.exists()){
                        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName, options);
                        remoteView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.ivwidgetimage, bm);
                    }
                    else{
                        remoteView.setImageViewResource(R.id.ivwidgetimage, R.drawable.defaultpic);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "Failed", e);
                }
```

I have already tried options.inSampleSize = 4; but that did not solve the problem.

Thanks for any explanations and help.

```
11-25 19:22:04.992: D/dalvikvm(59): GC_EXPLICIT freed 3148 objects / 171272 bytes in 107ms
11-25 19:22:05.092: V/MediaProvider(216): /mnt/sdcard volume ID: 318247957
11-25 19:22:05.201: D/dalvikvm(282): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 989 objects / 66344 bytes in 59ms
11-25 19:22:05.391: E/JavaBinder(59): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
11-25 19:22:05.401: D/dalvikvm(153): GC_EXPLICIT freed 4139 objects / 251136 bytes in 1278ms
```

Comment: Can you include the full stack trace?

Comment: It is not a lot of stack trace to work with, but maybe it has something to do with the android version 2.2 that allocated less memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For code like yours, this usually means that the bitmap is too large. You are limited to 1MB per Binder-based IPC transaction. I am not aware that this limit was raised in Android 4.x, though that is certainly possible.

Hence, make sure that `setImageViewBitmap()` uses a small enough `Bitmap`.

Comment: Thats strange. My image is about 300 kb big, so that should not be an issue. Is there way to set a bitmap to a maximum of lets say of 500 kb?

Comment: @Max: "My image is about 300 kb big" -- in memory or on disk? If you are citing an on-disk size, decoding the PNG/JPEG will take up a lot more heap space. "Is there way to set a bitmap to a maximum of lets say of 500 kb?" -- you can probably cook up a heuristic based on `inSampleSize`, though I don't have one handy.

Comment: You were right the ondisk size is 300 kb but the bitmap size was 547kb. When I scale it down to 500 kb it does not anymore give that error.